# Matlab code to generate virtual samples

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, noise

Can anyone please suggest me how to implement the function to generate virtual samples from the following [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7514991) in Matlab.

[image: paper]

I want to use it to generate more samples for training. I am using RGB images. for example:
[image]

**The code is originated from the answer provide by including the loops**

```
x = imread('IMG_1832.jpg');
for i=1:0.1:1.5
    for j=0:0.1:2
        alpha = i; % Some real valued number indicating the disturbance of light intensity
        beta = j; % Some real valued number indicating the amount of noise to add
        rng shuffle; % New random seed
        n = randn(size(x));
        y = alpha.*x + beta.*uint8(n);
        imshow(y);
        pause(0.2)
    end
end
```

Comment: You'll need a hyperspectral image, not an RGB image.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably do what you're after for a single cube, **x**, extracted from the larger hyperspectral cube:

```
x = ; % The extracted cube
alpha = 1.0; % Some real valued number indicating the disturbance of light intensity
beta = 1.0; % Some real valued number indicating the amount of noise to add
rng shuffle; % New random seed
n = randn(size(x));
y = alpha.*x + beta.*n;
```

For all the cubes in a hyperspectral image you could loop this code or you could load the entire hyperspectral cube into `x` (last (probably fourth or fifth) dimension being ***m***) and use the code vectorised.

Technically, the math in that snippet from the paper is saying you should have an *alpha* value for each ***x*** at index ***m***.

---

**Edit**

Here is code that will run for multiple cubes by using `for` loops:

```
HypIm = ; % The hyperspectral image
alpha = [1.0, , , , 1.0]; % Some array of real valued numbers indicating the disturbance of light intensity for each cube
beta = 1.0; % Some real valued number indicating the amount of noise to add
Ncubes = numel(alpha); % The number of cubes should be how many alpha values there are
rng shuffle; % New random seed

for m = 1:Ncubes
    x = HypIm(:,:,:,m); 
    n = randn(size(x));
    y(:,:,:,m) = alpha(m).*x + beta.*n;
end
```

You may want to check out the [hyperspectral image cube slicer](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40076-hyperspectral-image-cube-slicer) on *fileexchange* which allows you to obtain slices of a hyperspectral image.

Comment: I have updated the post with the code you have suggested by including the loop. Can you please check that

Comment: @Addee I will edit my answer to include the loop that I mention but you should probably add a description to your edited question indicating that the code originated from this answer (or remove it from the question completely).

Comment: @Addee If you give an example image in your question and if you reference the full paper I can provide a clearer answer.

Comment: I have updated the question. Also, in your code with `for`  loop. for one `x` image there is one `y` output. But I think it should be with one `x` image there should be multiple `y` output. Can you please check now

Comment: @ Addee The input needs to be a hyperspectral image (not an RGB image, https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/178617-how-to-convert-an-rgb-image-to-hyperspectral-image-in-matlab) reshaped so that the dimension with index ***m*** contains the extracted cubes. The paper gives illustrations and explanations of this.

Comment: You mean this method cannot apply on the RGB images?

Comment: @Addee looking again at the paper and your question, I don't think it can. The hyperspectral images have an extra dimension which looks to be vital for finding the virtual samples. What is described in the paper is not for RGB images (that I've seen) and if you applied the algorithm to RGB images instead of extracts of a hyperspectral image you would just get a bunch of noisy images. You could start with hyperspectral images and finish with virtual RGB images (https://doi.org/10.1109/JSTARS.2013.2272654) but I don't think you can start with RGB images using their method.

Comment: Ok, the reason I was making virtual images is for deep learning. In case, if I need to add noise and lightening effect I can do it like.. isn't?

Comment: I have discussed with the author of the paper about to use this method for the RGB images and he replied he believed that it can be used for the RGB images. 
"From my experience, it works on RGB images. There are some tips I'd like to share.
1. alpha should be aroudn 1.
2. beta should be small. You may change the super-parameter, and use grid search to find the best one."